# Looking for QGIS equivalent of ArcGIS "Delete Colormap" tool

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, style, colormap

I have many TIF rasters with colormaps. In ArcGIS I can delete these with ["Delete Colormap"](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/delete-colormap.htm) tool.

Is there a QGIS equivalent of this tool, or some other way of deleting them?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did not find ready made tool for that. Could be a good option to add into [gdal_edit.py](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html).

Meanwhile you can remove the colortable with GDAL and Python. Writing an empty colortable seems to effect like delete.

```py
from osgeo import gdal

ds = gdal.Open('palette.tif',gdal.GA_Update)
ct = gdal.ColorTable()
ds.GetRasterBand(1).SetRasterColorTable(ct)
ct = None
ds = None
```

Before:

```
Band 1 Block=1000x8 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  Color Table (RGB with 256 entries)
```

After:

```
Band 1 Block=1000x8 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```